# Python local package

Tags: python, package, local

I installed a package which I created locally using

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-python-package-without-publishing-e2d36c4686cd

as a guide.

After importing the package into a new python file, to try using the package I realized I had made an error in the original package.

MY question is, if I make changes to the code in the package, do I need to uninstall and reinstall, or will it automatically update?

Comment: if you built and installed a wheel package, you need to rebuild and reinstall. If you installed in development mode (`pip install -e`), the package is just a symlink to its sources, no need to reinstall

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must reinstall the package.  It should cost you nothing to try and fail.

cd to the directory containing setup.py and...

```
pip install .
```